# Connect docker container app (port 8080) to Nginx VPS host (default port 80)

Tags: docker, nginx

I have been trying to link my container app running on port 8080 to my nginx server running on an UbuntuVPS. I have read through similar questions on SO and saw what worked for some people, But it doesnt seem to work for me. On the nginx server, setting the proxy pass to localhost:8080 or the container IP with the (172.....:8080) doesnt work. The container name doesnt work;
Here is the server config:

````
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
        }


}
server {
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name lol.com;

        location /api {
                proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
return 301 $scheme://ihemyi.com:8080$request_uri;

        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ihemyi.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ihemyi.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}```
The app is a GOApp mapped to -p 8080:8080
If i access lol.com:8080/api/v10/, it works. but cant access lol.com/api/v10/. Please hoe do i fix this?
````

Comment: Can you reach the app on port 8080 from external? This might be related to docker network isolation.

Comment: Yes. The app is reachable on port 8080. Eg. **lol.com:8080** is accessible

Comment: Runs the container on the same host as nginx? Is nginx running as a container?

Comment: No Nginx is rin on the host. Not inside docker. I ran nginx inside the docker host and connected it using the same docker network and it worked. But i do not want to run nginx inside docker due to complications of lets encrypt